# Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of difference operator?

Tags: difference-equations

Consider the following difference operator

[image]

For `n=2` this operator action is given by:

```
n = 2;
tup = Tuples[{1, -1}, n];
LHS = Sum[ Product[((1 - Subscript[u, 1] Subscript[x, i]^tup[[qq, i]]) (1 - Subscript[u, 2] Subscript[x, i]^tup[[qq, i]]))/(1 - Subscript[ x, i]^(2 tup[[qq, i]])), {i, 1, n}] Product[(1 - t Subscript[x, i]^tup[[qq, i]] Subscript[x, j]^tup[[qq, j]])/(1 - Subscript[x, i]^tup[[qq, i]] Subscript[x, j]^tup[[qq, j]]), {j, 2, n}, {i, 1, j - 1}] f[Subscript[x, 1] q^(tup[[qq, 1]]/2), Subscript[x, 2] q^(tup[[qq, 2]]/2)], {qq, 1, Length[tup]}]
```

> [image: LHS]

Now I would like to use Mathematica to solve the difference equation

`LHS==EE f[Subscript[x,1],Subscript[x,2]]`

to find eigenfunctions `f` and eigenvalues `EE`. Is there a command in Mathematica that can do this? I looked online but could not find it.

PS:

There seems to be a recurrence relation solver `RSolve[]`, but it does not seem to be useful in the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution can be obtained by assuming `q == 1`.

```
Simplify[LHS /. {q -> 1}]
(* f[Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]] 
   (-1 + Subscript[u, 1] Subscript[u, 2]) (-1 + t Subscript[u, 1] Subscript[u, 2]) *)
```

So, the second line of this answer is `EE` in this case.  This immediately suggests a more general result, namely the eigenfunction `f` a constant and

```
EE = (-1 + Subscript[u, 1] Subscript[u, 2]) (-1 + t Subscript[u, 1] Subscript[u, 2])
```

as may be verified by evaluating

```
Simplify[LHS /. f[_, _] -> c]
```

It is not obvious (to me, at least) whether other solutions exist.  If they do, I am unaware of any single Mathematica function to find them.  One might be able to make some progress, however, by expanding `LHS` as a power series in `q` about `q == 1`.

Comment: Yes, that is my plan as well (expanding in `q->1` and effectively work with differential operators instead). I hoped there was a better way to automate the calculation for the full difference equation, but if it is not the case this will have to suffice.